# What is the best option to handle ETIMEDOUT in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, request

I`m trying to download more than 20000 files using multiples FOR loops that change variables on a specific link. It worked for a couple of minutes(around 600 files) and then a get an "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT". I`m implementing an error handler and thinking about using node-backoff or node-retry or just wait a little longer. But I would like to hear some thoughts about this, what would be the most optimal way to handle this problem? Any ideas?

I have already tried using different networks and computer, but I got the problem every time.

```
// looping variables for companies/reports and dates
async function main() {

  for (const [idxCompany, company] of companies.entries()) {

    for (const [idxReport, report] of reports.entries()) {

      for (const [idxYear, year] of years.entries()){

        for (const [idxMonth, month] of months.entries()) {     
          console.log(`${company} ${report} ${year} ${month}`)
          await Download(company, report, year, month)    

        }

      }

    }

  }

}

main ()


//Download files
  function Download(company, report, year, month) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const sendRequest =  request(`https://www.someWebsite.com/${year}${month}/${report}/${year}${month}-${report}-${company}.ZIP`)
    .on('response', function(response) {

      statusCodeResponse = response.statusCode

      if (statusCodeResponse == 200) {

        sendRequest.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${company} ${report}${year}${month}.zip`))
        sendRequest.on('close', function () {
          logger.info(` ${statusCodeResponse} ${company} ${report} ${year} ${month} OK`);
          console.log(`${statusCodeResponse} Done.`);
          resolve()
        })

      } else {

        logger.warn(` ${statusCodeResponse} ${company} ${report} ${year} ${month} Nothing`);
        console.log(`${statusCodeResponse} File dosent exist!`)
        resolve()

      }

    });

  });

}
```

The expected result is to write some information on the console/logging and pipe my files to the same folder.

But after a couple of minutes I got this error:

`events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 000.000.000.000:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Request.onRequestError (C:***********\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)`